# What does it mean to "provide credit"?

Tags: word-meaning

> Production was labour-intensive but required little in the way of
> investment. This was a welcome financial benefit, especially as the
> merchants provided accommodation and **credit** and salt in exchange for
> the peasants’ undertaking to deliver a certain number of barrels of
> tar. It was in the merchants’ interest to contract as many tar
> producers as possible.
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

What does author mean by "merchants provided credit" for peasants?

Does it mean that merchants gave loans to peasants?

Or does it mean that they allowed peasants to deliver their goods in a later date?

Comment: It's unclear from the context which it is. More likely it means loans, but without more information your guess is as good as mine

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the *credit* has anything to do with when the peasants completed their undertaking. The entire paragraph is focused on money -- production costs, investments, financial benefits and volume produced. There's really no mention of how long it takes anyone to do anything.

That said, it's unclear exactly what the merchants provided when they provided *credit*. They might have allowed the peasants to purchase food or other items before they had been paid, but that's just a guess. There's not enough information in the paragraph to know for sure.

Comment: It seems to me quite clear that it means what you hypothesise.